# What is the lifespan of a Spring Boot @RestController and an injected @Service?

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, groovy-sql

I have a @RestController which has an injected @Service bean. I am having trouble understanding the lifespan of the Controller and its Service. Is it on a per-request basis? Or is it longer than that? I am new to Spring and how beans are managed.

```
@RestController
class AppController {

    private final AppService appService

    AppController(AppService appService) {
        this.appService = appService
    }
    ...
}

@Service
class AppService {

    private final DataSource dataSource

    AppService(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource
    }

    private Sql getSql() {
        new Sql(dataSource.connection)
    }
    ...
}
```

The reason I ask is because we are instantiating a sql connection within the service and I am curious if I can memoize and reuse the connection or if I will have one instance per request that needs to be closed immediately.

Spring Boot 1.5.2

Comment: If you don't specify the scope for Spring components, the default scope is `singleton`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@RestController` is a shorthand for `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`. It respect the [MVC principles](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127624/what-is-mvc-really).

`@Service` is a specialisation of `@Component` and respect the [Business Service Facade pattern](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/ServiceFacade.htm) (in the Core J2EE patterns sense).

It follows that, the lifespan of these annotations is the lifespan of the whole application.

You can also read [Spring @Component, @Repository, @Service and @Controller Annotations](http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/how-to-use-spring-component-repository-service-and-controller-annotations/) for more information.

Comment: This is very helpful. I guess the basis for this question is that I am getting database pool connection exhaustion with this approach. Should I edit the original question or create a new one?

Comment: If it's a different question, create a new one.